# Is it possible to pass the function inside the format function? Code exiting with error code zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, format

```
def eight():
    return 8
def nine():
    return 9

def plus():
    print({ } + { }.format(eight(),nine()))
```

Is this a correct syntax? Can we pass a function inside format function, if i run this code it is not performing anything instead it is coming out with exit code 0.
My expected **output** is

```
17   //which is 8+9
```

the output which i am getting is:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

The **plus()** function should perform addition of two numbers, i am passing the numbers in the form of functions, whenever I call a function like **eight()** it should return the number eight.
Basically I am performing calculation using functions. Can anyone help me with this? Whether the syntax I used for format is correct or not? And is this the correct way. Thank you

Comment: Do you need `print(eight() + nine())`?

Comment: Yes @fas But not directly using print statement, but through add function created.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
def f1():
    print('f1')
    return 'f1-done'
    
print('f1 returned %s' % f1())
```

Output:

```
f1
f1 returned f1-done
```

Edit:

Code:

```
def eight():
    return 8
def nine():
    return 9

def plus():
    print('%d' % (eight() + nine()))   # 17

plus()
```

Comment: I didn't get the answer, the function will call like this --> seven(plus(two())), this should perform the desired operation. I think we need to use lambda and do, which I am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports the `format()` function for using only the built-in string class provides the ability to do complex variable substitutions and value formatting via the format().

To see more details please go through the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting)

You can use the below format to get the result.

```
def eight():
   return 8
def nine():
   return 9
def plus():
   print("{}".format(eight()+nine()))
```

You can also use to see the calculative format

```
def eight():
   return 8
def nine():
   return 9
def plus():
   print("{0} + {1} = {2}".format(eight(),nine(), eight()+nine()))
```